# What are some possible approaches for selecting best possible matches?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, pseudocode, sports-league-scheduling-problem

I have a hash of teams and possible matchups and each matchup is scored. Team A could play against Team B, C, OR D and each matchup has a score ->

```
   matches = 
                { 
                 Team A => [{name: B, score: 8}, {name: C, score: 10}, {name: D,score: 9}], 
                 Team B => [{name: A, score: 8}, {name: C, score: 7},{name: D,score: 7}],  
                 Team C => [{name: A, score: 10}, {name: B, score: 7}, {name: D,score: 6}],
                 Team D => [{name: A, score: 9}, {name: B, score: 7}, {name: C,score: 6}]
                }
```

I want to be able select only matchups where a team plays once. All that matters is that each matchup is above the minimum threshold So for example -> 7.

```
C -> A, D -> B would be acceptable
```

If all teams cannot be scheduled with the minimum scoring threshold. The threshold will be lowered and the process will start again. What are some possible way to approach this problem?

Currently how it's working ->
grouping all possible matchups above the threshold by team (Similar to the snippet) And ordering the list of match groups by group length (Smallest - Largest). Matching the most constrained teams first.

Comment: I see that `D -> B` has a score of `7` whereas `B -> D` has a score of `10`. I assume that's a typo as all of the remaining 5 pairwise comparisons have scores that are symmetric. Are we given a starting "threshold"? I can imagine using recursion, but I believe it will be a brute-force enumeration of combinations.

Comment: What do you optimize for: Do you want to find only one matching combination? Should the scores of both matches be the maximum possible score? Or should at least one match have the optimal score even if that means that the other match is not the maximum?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry for the late response. The starting threshold in this case can be 7 just as an example so most of the possible matches above would be acceptable except for those that have a score of 6 so just C -> D wouldn't be an acceptable match. Scoring  has already happened and is based on a combination of factors including competition and the number of times they have faced each other in the past few weeks. And yes that is a typo. Will fix now

Comment: @spickermann For now the goal is each team plays above the threshold while creating as many optimal matches as possible. So say there is 9 matches. It is ok if 5 matches have a score of 10 but four only have a score of 7. We just don't want to get bottlenecked where 5-6 matches have a score of 10+ but the rest of the remaining possible matches are below the minimum threshold.